# Trying Set Values Instead of copying and pasting

Tags: vba

I have been able to modify most of my VBA procedures to set ranges to equal other ranges to avoid copy and paste. It has speed up my code incredibly. However, there is a few cases where I can't figure out how to not use copy and paste. Below is one example:

```
Dim Creation2 As Worksheet
Dim HoleOpener As Worksheet
Dim Dal As Range
Dim Lad As Range
Dim Pal As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Set HoleOpener = Worksheets("HoleOpener")
LastRow = HoleOpener.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Creation2" And ws.Name <> "BitInfoTable" And ws.Name <> "DailyBitInfoTable" And ws.Name <> "BitRunInfoTable" And ws.Name <> "HoleOpener" Then
     Set Lad = ws.Cells.Find(What:="StartCopy", LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Resize(21, 25).Copy
     Sheets("HoleOpener").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
     Next
```

When I search I can't find any examples of doing something similar to this without copy/paste.

Comment: Your paste range is not fully qualified. Properly qualify your paste range, resize it to match your copy range. Instead of using copy/paste, just set them equal to each other

Comment: You want to check if value is found first.

Comment: Wow! I like how you get downvoted without explination for asking legitamate quesitons. At least have the balls to comment on why you downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You will simply need to swap the ranges I listed with your ranges in `FoundRange` and `PasteRange` and adjust the `Resize` to fit your needs (`(21, 25)`). You have to use `.value` here as well.

Here is a generic example of how to set two ranges equal to each other. Since your range is greater than one, you will need to ensure each range is of equal size in terms of rows and columns spanned.

---

```
Dim FoundRange As Range, PasteRange As Range

Set FoundRange = Range("A1:B10")  'Swap this for your found value ("Lad" in your code)
Set PasteRange = Range("C1").Resize(10, 2)   'Swap this for your destination value

PasteRange.Value = FoundRange.Value
```

---

Using the same logic as above & your code, the result will look something like this:

```
Dim Lad As Range, PasteRange As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Creation2" And ws.Name <> "BitInfoTable" And ws.Name <> "DailyBitInfoTable" And ws.Name <> "BitRunInfoTable" And ws.Name <> "HoleOpener" Then
        Set Lad = ws.Cells.Find(What:="StartCopy", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Resize(21, 25)
        Set PasteRange = Sheets("HoleOpener").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(21, 25)
        Destiation.Value = Lad.Value
    End If
Next ws
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you are finding a range that meets a specific criteria, copying that range and pasting it in a new range.

This is how I would solve it without using copy/paste:

1. Find range as you have done
2. Iterate all cells in range (by column or row)
3. Store value of each cell in a variable
4. Set value of destination cell to variable stored in Step 3

As you can guess, it will require a lot more code, so it really is a trade-off between spending time writing and maintaining more code or optimizing for performance